# How can we know whether Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor is present or not

Tags: intel, intel-mic

I want to run a program on Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor. How can I know whether my machine has an Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if it has one you should probably know as it is large (see pictures [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-phi-detail.html)), costly (several times the price of a desktop), and it generates a lot of heat (you need special fans) and drains a lot of electrical power (you need a special PSU).

otherwise `lspci | grep Co-processor` will tell you whether you have one or not.

Comment: why do you say it drains a lot of electric power. Doesn't it consume the same power as a dual socket sandy bridge?

Comment: @arunmoezhi indeed so it basically doubles the power needs of the computer it resides in.

Comment: Can we see that in lscpu also?

Comment: @DeepJoshi no for the PCI-card version, and probably yes for the stand-alone (bootable) version

Answer (score 3):

if you have a MIC (Xeon Phi) card attached to your machine then you would be able to ssh to it by `ssh mic0` command. This will only work if you installed [MPSS](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-manycore-platform-software-stack-mpss) though.